# How to iterate over all values of an Enum including any nested Enums?

Tags: python, enums

Imagine one has two classes derived from `Enum`, e.g.

```
class Color(Enum):
    blue = 'blue'
    red = 'red'

class Properties(Enum):
    height = 'h'
    weight = 'w'
    colors = Color
```

What is the best way to (probably recursively) iterate over all Enum-labels of a nested Enum like `Properties`, including the ones of `Enum`-members like `Properties.colors` in the example above (i.e. including  `Color.blue` and `Color.red`)? Checking for the type of the value?

Comment: It's not clear how you intend this to work. Should `blue` and `red` both be considered members of `Properties`, or do you want to list `Properties.height`, `Properties.weight`, `Properties.colors.blue`, and `Properties.colors.red`?

Comment: I don't think you want `Properties` to be an `Enum`, but rather something like a `NamedTuple`.

Comment: The iteration is supposed to run through the values ```Properties.height, Properties.weight, Color.blue, Color.red```. If the enumerations were nested deeper, the iteration should run through those values as well. @Samwise: the example is a bit contrived I admit, but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: In your question what exactly do you mean by "enum-labels"?

Comment: @bad_coder: ```Color``` has the labels ```blue``` and ```red```, Properties has the labels ```height, weight, colors```, but ```colors``` I want to resolve to its own labels, i.e. ```blue, red```.

Comment: @ctenar those are called "Enum names" not labels. For example, `Properties` has "enum member" `height` with name `height` and value `'h'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick example that just prints them out.  I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to make this a generic generator or whatever applies to the actual use case.  :)

```
>>> from typing import Type
>>> def print_enum(e: Type[Enum]) -> None:
...     for p in e:
...         try:
...             assert(issubclass(p.value, Enum))
...             print_enum(p.value)
...         except (AssertionError, TypeError):
...             print(p)
...
>>> print_enum(Properties)
Properties.height
Properties.weight
Color.blue
Color.red
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing it recursively is probably the best way. This example is slightly cleaner than using a try except block

```
import inspect

def iter_enum(e):
  for member in e:  
    if inspect.isclass(member.value) and issubclass(member.value, enum.Enum):
        iter_enum(member.value)
    else:
        print(member)

iter_enum(Properties)
```

Output

```
Properties.height
Properties.weight
Color.blue
Color.red
```